# The automorphism group of the complete binary rooted tree of height $3$

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, graph-theory, trees, automorphism-group

Can someone give me some help with this problem:

How do I find the automorphism group of the complete binary rooted tree of height $3$ ($15$ vertices)?
when an automorphism $F$ on a graph $G=(V,E)$ is defined as follows:

$\{v,u\}$ is an edge in $E$ iff $\{F(v),F(u)\}$ is an edge in $F(E)$.

I tried to start counting the permutations, but it seems there is a different and better way to approach the problem.

Comment: Well, it will be a non-abelian group of order $2^7=128,$ so that should narrow things down a bit, but there has to be a better way of going about it than that.

Comment: Can you explain why the size is 128?

Comment: Certainly. For clarity, the root of the tree will be called $\varnothing;$ the nodes of height one, $T,$ $F;$ of height two, $TT,$ $TF,$ $FT,$ $FF;$ of height three, $TTT,$ $TTF,$ $TFT,$ $TFF,$ $FTT,$ $FTF,$ $FFT,$ $FFF.$ $\varnothing$ has immediate successors $T,F,$ and if $N$ is the name of a node of height one or two, then its immediate successors are named $NT,NF.$ Hopefully, that's easy enough to visualize (draw a picture, if not). Now, let us construct an automorphism $f:G\to G,$ where $G$ is the complete binary rooted tree of height three. We *have* to have $f(\varnothing)=\varnothing.$

Comment: (cont'd) We must have either $f(T)=T$ or $f(T)=F$ ($2$ choices), and once we've decided on $f(T)$, we will have determined what $f(F)$ has to be. Now, if $N$ is the name of a node of height one or two (of which there are $6$), and if we have already determined $f(N),$ then either $f(NT)=f(N)T$ or $f(NT)=f(N)F$ ($2$ choices in each case), and once we have decided on $f(NT),$ we will have determined what $f(NF)$ has to be. In this way, we somewhat recursively define $f$, making $7$ choices between two possibilities, which uniquely determine the automorphism $f:G\to G$.

Comment: (cont'd) Put another way: (1) $f(\varnothing)=\varnothing;$ (2) two choices for $f(T),$ and our choice of $f(T)$ determines $f(T)$ and $f(F);$ (3) two choices for $f(TT),$ and our choice for $f(TT)$ determines $f(TT)$ and $f(TF);$ (4) two choices for $f(FT),$ and our choice for $f(FT)$ determines $f(FT)$ and $f(FF);$ (5) two choices for $f(TTT),$ and our choice for $f(TTT)$ determines $f(TTT)$ and $f(TTF);$ (6) two choices for $f(TFT),$ and our choice for $f(TFT)$ determines $f(TFT)$ and $f(TFF);$ (7) two choices for $f(FTT),$ and our choice for $f(FTT)$ determines $f(FTT)$ and $f(FTF);$

Comment: (8) two choices for $f(FFT),$ and our choice for $f(FFT)$ determines $f(FFT)$ and $f(FFF).$ Alternatively, an easy inductive argument shows that if $G$ is the complete binary tree of height $n\ge 0,$ then its automorphism group has order $$2^{2^n-1}.$$

Answer (score 21):

Let $G_n$ denote the automorphism group of the complete binary rooted tree of height $n$.  So, $G_1 \cong C_2$, the cyclic group of order $2$.

What about height $2$?  You have automorphisms switching one pair of leaves on the left and the other pair on the right (in the usual planar picture of the rooted tree).  Call these $a_1$ and $a_2$.  Together they generate a subgroup of $G_2$ that is isomorphic to $C_2 \times C_2$, the Klein $4$ group.  There is an additional automorphism generator, say $b$ that exchanges the left and right branches at the root.  $G_2 \cong \langle a_1, a_2, b \rangle$.  In fact the subgroup $\langle a_1, a_2 \rangle$ is normal in $G_2$, and
$$
G_2 \cong (C_2 \times C_2) \rtimes C_2.
$$
This construction is called a [wreath product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wreath_product) and can be written
$$
C_2 \wr C_2.
$$

---

Now, for height $3$ (and beyond), we iterate the construction.  There are two isomorphic copies of $G_2$ in $G_3$ generated by the subtrees on either side of the root.  The direct product of these two generate a normal subgroup inside of $G_3$, permuted by one additional generator at the root.  So,
$$
\begin{align}
G_3 &\cong (G_2 \times G_2) \rtimes C_2 \\
&\cong \bigg( \big( (C_2 \times C_2) \rtimes C_2 \big) \times \big( (C_2 \times C_2) \rtimes C_2 \big) \bigg) \rtimes C_2,
\end{align}
$$
a group of order $2^7 = 128$, generated by $7$ involutions.

In other words, $G_3$ is an iterated wreath product:
$$
G_3 \cong G_2 \wr C_2 \cong \big( C_2 \wr C_2 \big) \wr C_2.
$$

---

Beyond $n = 3$, we have the recursive formula
$$
G_{n + 1} \cong G_n \wr C_2 \cong \big( G_n \times G_n \big) \rtimes C_2,
$$
which gives the recurrence relation for the orders of the automorphism groups:
$$
\big| G_{n + 1} \big| = 2\big| G_n \big|^2.
$$
Together with the base case $\big| G_1 \big| = 2$, the can be solved to show that
$$
\big| G_n \big| = 2^{2^n - 1}.
$$

Comment: This is an under-appreciated answer. +1

Comment: Also worth noting that $G_n$ is isomorphic to the sylow-$2$ subgroups of the symmetric group on $2^n$ points.

Comment: mind commenting while we need a semidirect product here? for me it looks like the third $C_2$  (related to the generaor $b$) is also a normal subgroup and so we would have $G_2 = (C_2\times C_2)\times C_2$ etc. but i seems to miss something

Comment: No, the subgroup $\langle b \rangle = \{1, b\}$ is not normal in $G_2$. Notice that $a_1 b a_1 \not\in \langle b \rangle$ as it has both branches swapped at the root and both pairs of leaves swapped as well. As a permutation of the leaves from left-to-right, it's $4321$ in one-line permutation notation.

Comment: thanks @SammyBlack makes sense! Cool construction,...