# binary tree 1-15 total arrangements

Tags: combinatorics

[image]

can't figure out if there is a way to systematically counting the arrangement - there are lots of them. Would appreciate any insight. Thanks!

Comment: Hint: The answer is $\binom{14}{7} \binom{6}{3}^2 \binom{2}{1}^4$.

Comment: But if you want the number of arrangements "up to symmetry of the graph", divide the answer in my comment above by $2^7$.  (See here for reference: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/564194/the-automorphism-group-of-the-complete-binary-rooted-tree-of-height-3.)

Answer (score 2):

The $15$ has to go at the top. Then you can choose any $7$ numbers to go in the left half. Then the two greatest numbers in each half need to go at the top. And so on.